# NSUserDefaults: How to display user defaults when valueforKey is an ENUM

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsuserdefaults

In iPhone app, How to display values in console for user defaults when valueforKey is an ENUM?

Currently with the below code if I try to display in console then it crashes with no crash log in console.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:Enum]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fetch:

```
int someValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] integerForKey:@"your key here"];
```

to save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setInteger:10 forKey:@"your key here"];
```

EDIT: got it, you crash because in NSLog you are using the wrong format:

```
NSLog(@"%i",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:Enum]);
```

try %i (to print integers) instead of %@ (used to print valid objective-c objects)

Comment: This is not what I want. I have edited my question. Please check it out

Answer (score 4):

Since an `enum` is really just a fancy way of displaying an `int`, all you have to do is create an `enum` variable and set it to the value you get from `NSUserDefaults`.

You may end up with something like:

```
PirateEnumType pirateType = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"PirateType"];
```

EDIT:

I'm sorry. I guess I didn't fully understand your question. Since an `enum` is really an `int`, you will need to use "%i" to display it instead of "%@".

In order to show it properly as a human readable string, you would need to have some sort of `enumToString` function, perhaps like:

```
-(NSString*)enumToString:(PirateEnumType)enumValue {
    NSString* returnValue = @"";

    switch (enumValue) {
        case Captain:
            returnValue = @"Captain";
            break;
        case Swashbuckler:
            returnValue = @"Swashbuckler";
            break;
        case PegLeg:
            returnValue = @"PegLeg";
            break;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I have edited my question. Please check it out

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` objects are really just `NSDictionary` objects. `NSDictionary` only takes an object as a key. Enum is just an integer, so you can't use it as a key directly. One way to do it, though is to use `NSNumber`, which can represent an integer as an object like the following:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefults] valueForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:yourEnum];
```

To set the value you would do:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setValue:yourValue forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:yourEnum]];
```

Comment: @CharlieMezak: This is not what I want. I have edited my question. Please check it out.

Comment: @CharlieMezak: Thanks for the input. In my case with the code I have got, the code is using the Enum Constants as value for key to the NSUserDefaults. This is where I get the crash. What could be done?

Comment: Can you post the line of code that is causing the crash (as an edit to your question)?

Comment: This is the line causing the crash `NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:Enum]);` Can you please help?

Comment: I thought I already addressed this in my answer. You CAN'T use an enum as the key. An Enum is an integer, not at object. Where is this Enum variable declared? Can you post that code?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. Firstly, an enum cannot be a key in valueForKey. valueForKey can only accept strings, not string values of enums. Therefore, you need to implement a method to get a string value from an enum. In my example below that method is stringFromEnum. Here is [one example of how to get a string from an enum](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/12/01/not-so-nasty-enums-in-objective-c/).

Sometimes I've seen NSLog choke when I ask it to directly include the return value of a message sent to an object. I've always found that assign the result of that message to an instance variable first and then passing the value of that instance variable into NSLog instead solved the problem, but admit I haven't figured out what the relevant factors are that determine when it does or does not work the original way. Interested in any comments.

```
NSString *myKey = [self stringFromEnum:Enum];
NSString *myStringToLog = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:myKey];
NSLog(@"%@", myStringToLog);
```

Another reading of your question could be that your instance variable Enum is actually a string, which is the Key for an enum that will be returned from NSUserDefaults. However, that can't be the case, as NSUserDefaults will not store an enum. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Tasks/UsingDefaults.html) for object types that are supported. If that's what you're trying to do, your problem may be partly in other code where you're trying to store the enum in the first place?